# Recaptcha: An internal error occurred

Tags: django, captcha

I'm using [Recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create) within Django. I was using the following tutorial to integrate it in my web application: http://www.marcofucci.com/tumblelog/26/jul/2009/integrating-recaptcha-with-django/

The captcha doesn't show up on my machine. Instead of the captcha the following error message is displayed:

> An internal error occurred: 4A6376441D250.ADE1949.3546A435

(I get a different code each time).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To which domain did you sign the recaptcha? If you entered "127.0.0.1" in the registration make sure you use this one and not "localhost".

Answer (score 2):

Today, I got this error on one of my client's website.
It was working great but  suddenly it stop working. Then upon googling I find  [this link](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/troubleshooting) and renewed my API key.

But after I switched to Secure (SSL Enabled) side of my website then It stops working again.

Then, In I got this function there

> recaptcha_get_html(**PUBLIC_KEY**, **$error**, **true**);

The third argumentation use the SSL Server, I've to enable it.
This fixed everything for me.

Comment: Deleting and recreating my key fixed this problem. Thanks!